# Does collectgarbage in Lua also include memory consumed by lua_shared_dict?

Tags: nginx, lua, out-of-memory, openresty

I am trying to debug OOM error that I get in my application using openresty. I see that adding collectgarbage("collect") followed by collectgarbage("count") in my lua scripts might be one of the possibilities to debug the issue. But does collectgarbage("count") count memory consumed by [`lua_shared_dict`](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/#ngxshareddict) as well?

If not, what would be alternative to check memory consumed by `lua_shared_dict`(s)?

Suggestions to debug OOMs in openresty app are also appreciated.

Comment: `lua_shared_dict` is not a core Lua symbol. Perhaps it's something from OpenResty?

Comment: [reference for lua shared dict](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/#ngxshareddict)